# C - linked-lists for loop doubts

Tags: c, list, dealloc

I am unsure on which way to dealloc my `list` of `Item`. Each `list` has a first and last item, and each `item` is linked to a `nextItem` until it is null.

```
for(myItem=list.firstItem; myItem!=list.lastItem; myItem=myItem->nextItem)
    dealloc(myItem);
```

or

```
for(myItem=list.firstItem; myItem!=NULL; myItem=myItem->nextItem)
    dealloc(myItem);
```

`myItem->nextItem = NULL` if `myItem=list.lastItem`.

I am unsure if using the first declaration of the for will dealloc all of  `myItem` or if the lastItem will not be dealloc. (I believe this is what will happen.)
On the other hand, i am unsure if the second declaration will make everything crash/not work properly when you assign to `NULL`a `myItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both programs have undefined behavior, because you dereference `myItem` pointer after it has been deallocated. This is not allowed, and may crash your program.

A proper way to deallocate a linked list is with a `while` loop, when you get the `next` pointer first, and only then deallocate the node:

```
ItemNode *myItem = list.firstItem;
while (myItem != NULL) {
    ItemNode *tmp = myItem;
    myItem = myItem->nextNode;
    dealloc(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you too, Ill use this way.

Answer (score 0):

Note that both ways are incorrect. Due to how for loops are implemented, you are referencing `myItem` after it has been dealloced. You need to write something like:

```
for(myItem=list.firstItem; myItem!=NULL; ) {
    nextItem = myItem->nextItem
    dealloc(myItem);
    myItem = nextItem;
}
```